# Create object from response api symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I'm trying to encapsulate data from my symfony api.

There is my serialization.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Parcs:
attributes:
    id:
        groups: ['parcs']
    latitude:
        groups: ['parcs']
    longitude:
        groups: ['parcs']
    sac:
        groups: ['parcs']
    name:
        groups: ['parcs']
```

And there is my `ParcsController`:

```
 /**
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"parcs"})
 * @Rest\Get("/parcs")
 */
public function getParcsAction(Request $request)
{
    $parcs = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Parcs')
            ->findAll();
    /* @var $parcs Parc[] */

    return $parcs;
}
```

With those data i want to get `[id, sac, name, Coordinate[latitude, longitude]]`.

PS : I'm still learning symfony if you have a good tutorial I'll be happy too. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only defined groups there, but you haven't actually 'used' them with the serializer. You need to install and configure Serializer Component
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Next, you'd want to extend `AbstractController` which has a neat `json()` method that will automatically figure out that the `serializer` service is loaded and will automatically serialize your data.

```
 // extends AbstractController

 /**
* @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"parcs"})
* @Rest\Get("/parcs")
*/
public function getParcsAction(Request $request)
{
   ... everything you said

return $this->json($parcs);
}
```

EDIT:
Also, I see you're expecting `latitude` and `longitude` to be a part of different object (from your response example). If that's the case, you need to define those two properties as part of that new object (`serialization.yml`). They can't be part of `Parcs` entity, you'd need to create a new one.